# How to use ordered list <ol> in a table and numbering each table row <tr>

Tags: html, html-lists, html-table

I have an HTML table used to display some information in the correct form.

Now, my goal is to number each table row.

For that, I have tryed to use ordererd list and list items inside the table but it seems not to work.

Do you have an idea and an example on how to do this. Thank you.

Comment: add another column to the table and number your rows

Comment: @MuraliPrasanth, thanks, but how to know the number of the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about HTML you you can definitely do this in jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $('table thead tr').prepend('<th>#</th>');
    $('table tbody tr').each(function () {
        i += 1;
        $(this).prepend('<td>' + i + '</td>');
    });
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BUTS5/)

**UPDATE**

If you want numbers only on specified class (number) then try:

```
$(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $('table thead tr').prepend('<th>#</th>');
    $('table tbody tr').each(function () {

         i += 1;

        if($(this).hasClass('number')) {
            $(this).prepend('<td>' + i + '</td>'); 
        } else {
            $(this).prepend('<td></td>');
        }
    });
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BUTS5/1/)

Comment: Thank you Gurpreet, but in my case, i need to number a `<tr>` inside the table, not the `<td>`. Could you please give me an example of that. PS: And a +1 for you.

Comment: I didn't get that, include desired mark-up in your question then I'll update answer accordingly.

Comment: Oups, my mistake, the demo works well. I will try it in my project and if fine, I will accept the answer, if not, I will ask you for help :). Thank you

Comment: One question please, where to put this function? When to call it?

Comment: Ok, it allmost work now, but is it possible to execute this onn only certain rows, with a certain class for example

Comment: call it on jQuery's document.ready and it'll find your table. If you have got multiple tables the give your target table an id and update $('table thead tr') selector with specified id.

Comment: Thank you, but what if I would like to execute this on a certain td class only?

Comment: I put +1 for each of your comments :)

Comment: Any way to get it without JQuery? I doubt that LibreOffice supports JQuery *(and fwiw I didn't get it working even in a simple html being opened in firefox)*.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, here is a single line selector for getting all the first TDs in a table - excluding THs.
I then add whatever element I want, before them. In this case, I print a counter variable, to enumerate the rows. The effect is I am making the table rows numbered.

```
var counterVariable = 1;
var mySpanClass = ""; //to style the numbering...

    $(".myTableClass tr:not(:first) td:first-child").before(function(){ return "<span class='" + mySpanClass + "'>" + counterVariable++ + "</span>"; });
```